# "Numbers"are allowed in rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been thinking if we can use a kind of "numbers" in abstract rings with unit. We can define 2 by $1+1$, 3 by $1+1+1$, etc. If the ring is a field we can have fractions of "numbers", for example, if $x\in F$, $F$ a field, we are allowed to say $x/2$, where $1/2$ is the inverse of $1_F+1_F$, $1_F$ the identity in $F$.

The advantage of these "numbers" is we can have the same properties of the numbers ($\mathbb N, \mathbb Q$) themselves.

Is my reasoning right?

Thanks

Comment: What if $1_F + 1_F = 0_F$?

Comment: not the same properties, no. For any natural number $n$ and any ring element $r,$ you can define $nr$ as the sum of $n$ copies of $r;$  this is not ambiguous. On the other hand, this might be $0$ or otherwise unpredictable.

Comment: @WillJagy If the characteristic of the ring is $0$, does my reasoning works?

Comment: @Calle you're right!

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is: sort of.

You've got the right idea. Given a ring $R$ with unit it is certainly reasonable to define "numbers" the way you have. In fact, you're really getting at the fact that there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\to R$. What you are interested in are the  images of this map. That is, here you define $2_R:=\phi(2)$ and generally $n_R=\phi(n)$.

Of course, $\phi$ doesn't necessarily carry over the "properties" you speak of identically. For example, for $R=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ we have $0_R=2_R=4_R=\dotsb$.

So the question you are really asking is: what ring-homomorphism properties does $\phi$ have? The answer to this question completely depends on the ring in question.

Comment: My real problem is I would like to define a sum (+) in $F^2$, and I would like to know if I can write: $(X_1,Y_1)(+)(X_2,Y_2)=(\frac{X_1+Y_1}{2},\frac{X_2+Y_2}{2})$ where + is the sum in the field.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Whoops. I've been thinking contravariantly too long $\operatorname{Spec}(R)\to\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$

Comment: You can do that as long as $F$ is not of characteristic 2, although that's not the most usual sum on $F^2$. All you need is for $1/2=2^{-1}$ to be uniquely defined: $2$ is just the image of $2$ under Brian's $\phi$, which has an inverse in any field not of characteristic 2.

Comment: @KevinCarlson but it doesn't sound strange? is it usual to use "numbers" in this way?

Comment: It's quite usual. It's a bit unintuitive in fields of positive characteristic, but $\mathbb{Q}$ embeds in every field of characteristic zero in a unique way so then there's actually nothing strange about it at all.

Comment: @KevinCarlson and OP: averaging two numbers is not an associative operation.

Comment: @seaturtles Thanks for the observation. I was only responding to whether the expression was well-defined, although perhaps the use of the word "sum" should indicate the OP is trying to define a group structure on $F^2$.

Comment: @seaturtles thanks for the remark, but it doesn't matter, I wanted to know just if the fraction part is well defined.